# How to reference for multiple index .innerHTML method

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

How do I specify .innerHTML for multiple index of array?
i have an array

```
let poles = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".pole"));
```

And it contains 9 empty divs , like this :

```
<div class="pole" id="1"></div>
```

When someone click on that div, it will `innerHTML` X or O because it a tic tac toe game.

How make like this :

```
poles[0][1][2].innerHTML ==='X'
```

or

```
poles[0, 1, 2].innerHTML === 'X'
```

Instead of this:

```
if(poles[0].innerHTML === 'X' && poles[1].innerHTML === 'X' && poles[2].innerHTML === 'X')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we can do is use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the first 3 items from the array, then we can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on those items to see if every item has an `innerHTML` of `X` like this:

```js
poles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div > span'))

let first3 = poles.slice(0, 3)
// We could also build the array manually like this, which will be needed
// for when testing for diagonal matches
// let first3 = [poles[0], poles[1], poles[2]]

if (first3.every(i => i.innerHTML === 'X')) {
  console.log('Row 1 contains all x')
} else {
  console.log('Row 1 doesn\'t contain all x')
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>X</span>
  <span>X</span>
  <span>X</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

If we change one to contain `O` like this we get a result saying it isn't contained:

```js
poles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div > span'))

let first3 = poles.slice(0, 3)

if (first3.every(i => i.innerHTML === 'X')) {
  console.log('Row 1 contains all x')
} else {
  console.log('Row 1 doesn\'t contain all x')
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>X</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>X</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I have taken this even further, and created a function that will test for a win based on what was passed. Just call the function `testWin()` with `X` or `O` as a parameter.

- We create a function with an array of possible wins
- We loop over all the possible wins
- We create a temporary array of elements using map to map over the poles to get 3 items
- We finally test if every item's innerHTML contains `X` or `O` based on what was passed as a parameter

```js
poles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div > span'))

function testWin(player) {
  // An array of all possible wins
  let wins = [
    // Horizontal
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    // Vertical
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    // Diagonal
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ]

  // Loop through each possible win and test if there is a win
  for (let i in wins) {
    // Get a list of items from the poles array based on each win record
    let itms = wins[i].map(key => poles[key])
    // Test the array to see if it is a valid win
    if (itms.every(itm => itm.innerHTML === player)) {
      return {win: true, line: i, player}
    }
  }
  // No win was found, return false
  return {win: false, player}
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(testWin('X')))
console.log(JSON.stringify(testWin('O')))
```

```css
div > span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>X</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>O</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span>X</span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>X</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh its good solution, but what if i have one row diagonally, like this ? `(poles[0].innerHTML === player1 && poles[4].innerHTML === player1 && poles[8].innerHTML === player1)` , i  can't slice it like you :/

Comment: I have added a dynamic function that test for a player's win. see the last snippet

Comment: Ye i see, it works, but now, how i can do this for 8 win conditions, i'll declare 8 variables like this with slices?

Comment: if you could explain me with more details, how it works this for in, with map and every, i'll be very happy full :)

Comment: I am not sure I can explain any more. It is explained the best I could do in the bullet point list and comments in the code. If there is something specific that you don't understand, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var bol = true;
for (var x = 1, x<4, x++) {
   if (poles[x].innerHTML != "X") {
      bol = false;
   }
}
if (bol) {
   //There are only X
} else {
   //There are not only X
}
```